# Custom equation command produces not wanted indentation

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, indentation

I wrote this custom environment to save time when typing:

```
\newenvironment{equations}
    {\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}}
    {\end{aligned}\end{equation}}
```

However, it produces a strange indentation in the text that follows.

Directly writing

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
     things
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

does not give any problem.

What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question had already been asked: the trick is to add `\ignorespacesafterend` immediately after `\end{equation}` in the definition of `equations`. Don't worry about the duplicate: finding them is not easy even for regulars. I hope you'll have a great time with TeX and the site.

Comment: Thank you @egreg!
I'm sorry I'm thanking you just now.